# utorrent freeze after started

Tags: windows-server-2008, bittorrent

When I start UTorrent on Windows Server 2008 it freezes. It was running perfectly fine after I installed it for the first time

Comment: Probably not a good question for ServerFault.

Comment: Did you try uninstalling it? Then reinstall it? After uninstalling it search the hard drive for any relevant folders and delete them before reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this problem before. I thought they had fixed it.

uTorrent is attempting to check the pieces of a torrent that it has lost track of. When you launch the aplication, immediately pause all of your torrents by focusing on the list, typing ctrl-a, and hitting pause. It might take a few tries.

From there, you can isolate the torrent that is giving you problems. Delete and re-add it or just forget about it.